# Pythonic way to parse the output of `zpool status` into a dictionary - inconsistent output causing messy code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse the output of the zfs command `zpool status`, which gives me an output like so:

```bash
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 35.6G in 00:08:47 with 0 errors on Sat Sep 10 01:20:26 2022
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

My goal is to convert this output to a dictionary, like so

```py
{
    'pool': 'tank',
    'state': 'ONLINE',
    'scan': 'resilvered 35.5G in...',
    'config': 'NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM...',
    'errors': 'No known data errors'
}
```

I'm experiencing two problems that are causing me to write messy code:

1. Not every line, such as the `scan` line, is displayed every time the command is run, and [additional lines are possible that are not displayed above](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcve/index.html#:%7E:text=This%20section%20in,known%20data%20errors.:%7E:text=This%20section%20in,known%20data%20errors.)
2. The `config` line has a few newlines before its output, which makes splitting difficult

I've tried a few different ways of doing this, but my code gets bogged-down with a bunch of conditionals - and being python I figured there must be a cleaner way.

This is the "cleanest" method I've found, but it's not super-readable and it doesn't work with the `config` line:

```py
# output = `zpool status` output
d = {}

for entry in map(lambda x: x.strip(), output.split('\n')):
    if 'state' in entry:
        pool_state = entry.split(' ')
        key = pool_state[0]
        val = pool_state[1]
        d[key] = val
    if 'status' in entry:
        ...
    if 'config' in entry:
        # entry does not contain output of the config: line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [re.spit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and splitting on keys (state, scan) that are at the beginning of the line separated by `:` and then converting them to dictionary using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

You can also parse config to list of dictionaries.

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

s = """  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 35.6G in 00:08:47 with 0 errors on Sat Sep 10 01:20:26 2022
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors"""

def parse_data(data):
    parts = re.split(r'(?:\n|^)\s*(\w*):\s*', data.strip(), re.MULTILINE)[1:]
    parsed = dict(zip(parts[::2], parts[1::2]))
    return {
        **parsed,
        'config': parse_config(parsed.get('config', ''))
    }


def parse_config(data):
    lines = [v.strip().split() for v in data.splitlines() if v.strip()]
    if lines:
        return [
            dict(zip(lines[0], v))
            for v in lines[1:]
        ]
    return []
    

pprint(parse_data(s))
```

Output should be:

```py
{'config': [{'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'tank',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'raidz2-0',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'sda',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'sdc',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'sdb',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'sdd',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'},
            {'CKSUM': '0',
             'NAME': 'sdf',
             'READ': '0',
             'STATE': 'ONLINE',
             'WRITE': '0'}],
 'errors': 'No known data errors',
 'pool': 'tank',
 'scan': 'resilvered 35.6G in 00:08:47 with 0 errors on Sat Sep 10 01:20:26 '
         '2022',
 'state': 'ONLINE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
s = """  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 35.6G in 00:08:47 with 0 errors on Sat Sep 10 01:20:26 2022
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors"""

res = {}
for line in s.splitlines():
    if line == "":  # Ignore everything after the last x: v
        break
    k, v = line.lstrip(" ").split(":", 1)
    if v:
        res[k] = v.lstrip(" ")
```

Result:

```
{'pool': 'tank', 'state': 'ONLINE', 'scan': 'resilvered 35.6G in 00:08:47 with 0 errors on Sat Sep 10 01:20:26 2022'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't put the `config` or `errors` lines in the dictionary - I realize now that I wasn't clear enough with the example dictionary I provided. I've edited my question to be more clear.